# Working(details) of kali linux on usb persistent flash drive

Tags: linux, kali-linux, live-usb, persistence

I made a persistent usb drive for kali linux but there are some issues and i and i want some detail working of booting up an os from usb stick

### Issues

1. some programs don't get started when launched
2. after 1st step when i try to see the details by right clicking on the program then the details don't show or if they show up then a window [image: popping of details in new window] but i don't know, what is it can someone explain m what is it
3. In mozilla devnagiri(language) language isn't getting rendered properly and also some functions won't work sometimes and also sometimes browser get crashed

### About my partitions on usb

> my usb is 16GB capacity and i used 3.5GB of iso image of kali and followed [this tutorial](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/install-kali-live-usb-drive-with-persistence-optional-0162253/) for making a persistent usb drive and after that i gave 11GB for persistent partition and rest 5GB for my OS
> ***my ques is, should i increase the space for os by decreasing the persistent storage space and if yes then how can i modify the partition size without reinstalling the os***

### Questions

1. How my functions are working is it on RAM or it's on usb?
2. Once when my pc was in sleep mode my accidentally removed my usb drive but then also i was able to login again and launch terminal and able to shutdown my pc, why the OS didn't crashed?
3. Is there any small link with my HDD at all while booting up from usb at the start?

Comment: It is possible that your Kali system was damaged, when you removed the USB drive, and that your problems are caused by that damage. You could try to repair the file system in the partition for persistence. But maybe it is easier (and it is certainly more likely to succeed) to make a fresh installation of Kali persistent live (1. with the same method or 2. according to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/minp) (if you have another system with linux). See also [the details](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/minp/details)

Comment: 1. Both on RAM and USB. At least when you run persistent live, the partition for persistence is overlayed with the root partiiton; 2. Possible cause to your problems; 3. No link that is part of the operating system's function, but some partition on the HDD might be mounted.

Comment: @sudodus the possible cause for the problem which you are telling it is not like that because, all the issues which i mentioned was also there before. can you explain me that issue 2 in my question

Comment: In order to give more relevant help I need more details. Please tell me **which program** that does not work, and if you are connected to the internet, when you try to launch the program. -- Also, have you added some software to your Kali system (that software might interfere with the program that you try to launch)?

Comment: The system **might** crash (will probably crash), if you unplug the USB drive while it is running. But not necessarily. If some system critical file is buffered in RAM and not yet written to the partition for persistence, there will be problems. But this is not always the case. I think in your case, when the system was sleeping, it had already flushed the buffers (written the buffered data to files in the partition for persistence).

Comment: @sudodus i recently installed google chrome but after clicking on it the cursor gives buffer symbol but after 5sec it gets normal and no google chrome is launched and if i try see the details of it then the issue 2 is raised can you explain me that please and yes i always connected to the internet while launching the programs

Comment: Did you install the proprietary Chrome or the free `chromium-browser`? How did you install it (from which source, with which commands or tool)?

Comment: it's a proper installation from google web and also it's google chrome and chromium browser also not getting launched though chromium had came pre-installed with OS and to install chrome i first downloaded the latest .deb package and then installed it using  `apt install /pat/to/pack.deb`

Comment: I don't know, what problems should be expected with google chrome. Maybe it would help if you remove all traces of chromium-browser before installing google chrome. Please remember that Kali is a very specialized distro with security focus. Maybe there is something related to security that will prevent google chrome from working.

Comment: @RahulGupta I would read [this section of the Official Kali Linux documentation](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux#Is-Kali-Linux-Right-For-You?). It covers that installing none included software even as "trivial" as Steam or a different version of a programming language, is not supported. Ask yourself why the proprietary version of Chrome is needed in a _penetration testing_ distribution that the provided web browser would not suffice?